# python code- function does not work for arithmatic quiz and password does not work

Tags: python

Please could I have some help with my code, as the function does not work for the `NumberError()` The point is that if when answering the maths quiz you type in a letter by mistake, it will say 'PLEASE TYPE IN A NUMBER', however I cannot get it to work as an error keeps coming up:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Helen/Documents/Computer Science Summer Task/Helen_Summer Tasks-1_2_3.py", line 77, in <module>
    StudentAnswer = int(input("Please answer the question: "))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'g'
```

Here is what I have attempted so far:

```
def NumberError():
    if StudentAnswer not in Turns '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10':
            print('Please enter a NUMBER.')
    else:
        return ("\nQuestion")
```

Also the password option to access the quiz does not fully work: Here is what I have so far and I would appreciate it if I could have some help on what I need to do right and what I am doing wrong.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
window = tk.Tk()


import os

#Must Access this to continue.


def checkPassword():
    password = "Starfish"
    def enteredPassword():
        passwordEntry.get()
    if password == enteredPassword:
        confirmLabel.config(text="Access granted")
    else:
        confirmLabel.config(text="Access denied")

passwordLabel = tk.Label(window, text="Password:")
passwordEntry = tk.Entry(window, show="*")

button = tk.Button(window, text="Enter", command=checkPassword)
confirmLabel = tk.Label(window)

passwordLabel.pack()
passwordEntry.pack()
button.pack()
confirmLabel.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

THIS IS MY OVERALL PIECE OF CODE SO FAR:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
window = tk.Tk()


import os

#Must Access this to continue.


def checkPassword():
    password = "Starfish"
    def enteredPassword():
        passwordEntry.get()
    if password == enteredPassword:
        confirmLabel.config(text="Access granted")
    else:
        confirmLabel.config(text="Access denied")

passwordLabel = tk.Label(window, text="Password:")
passwordEntry = tk.Entry(window, show="*")

button = tk.Button(window, text="Enter", command=checkPassword)
confirmLabel = tk.Label(window)

passwordLabel.pack()
passwordEntry.pack()
button.pack()
confirmLabel.pack()

window.mainloop()

#Summer_Task1.py
import random
def get_Name():
    global Name
    global Class
#Inputs pupil's class
while True:
    Class = input ("Please select your class: A)Class 1 B)Class 2 C)Class 3 [C1/C2/C3]? : ")

    # check if d1a is equal to one of the strings, specified in the list
    if Class in ['C1', 'C2', 'C3']:
        # process the input
        print("Thank you.")
        # if it was equal - break from the while loop
    break

def start_quiz():
    print("Welcome to the Numeracy quiz that will test your basic arithmatic skills!")
Name = input("Please enter your first name and surname: ")
print("Hi " + Name + "!" + " Please ANSWER the following NUMERACY QUESTIONS and then PRESS ENTER to work out whether they are RIGHT or WRONG. Please ENTER  a NUMBER.")
print("You will receive a total score at the end of the quiz.")
def Questions():
    global score
    global questionnumber
Score = 0
questionnumber=0
while questionnumber<10:
        questionnumber=questionnumber+1 
        Turns = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
for n in Turns:
    Number1 = random.randint(1, 10)
    Number2 = random.randint(1, 10)
    Number3 = random.randint(1, 3)

    if Number3 == 1:
        Answer = Number1 + Number2
        Sign = " + "
    elif Number3 == 2:
        Answer = Number1 - Number2
        Sign = " - "
    elif Number3 == 3:
        Answer = Number1 * Number2
        Sign = " x "
    print("\nQuestion", n, "\n", Number1, Sign, Number2)
    StudentAnswer = int(input("Please answer the question: "))
    print("The correct answer is:", Answer)
    if StudentAnswer == Answer:
        Score = Score + 1
        print("Well Done, that is correct!")
    else:
        print("Sorry that is incorrect!")
def NumberError():
    if StudentAnswer not in Turns '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10':
            print('Please enter a NUMBER.')
    else:
        return ("\nQuestion")  

print("\nName:", Name)
print("\nClass:", Class)
print("\nScore:", Score)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could test the input type rather than casting it as an int

```
i = input("Please answer the question: ")
if(not type(i) is int):
    print('Please enter a NUMBER.')
```

Comment: Thanks very much @Owen Doyle

Comment: I'm wondering if anyone could tell me what I could do to improve the password function???